# Why does innerHTML only give me the last value of the for loop?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

I am an absolute javascript layman.

I made a simple for loop and wanted to output the value of **i** in a div.

Unfortunately, only the last value is displayed.

But why does console.log (i) show me every value of **i** in the console?

```js
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  let myBlock = document.getElementById('myblock');
  console.log(i)
  myBlock.innerHTML = i;
}
```

```html
<div id="myblock"/>
```

Comment: The browser does not update the view on every update, generally.

Comment: `console.log(i)` doesn't overwrite the previous logs but `myBlock.innerHTML = i;` overwrites the previous innerHTML.

Comment: You aren't appending the value to the element and overwriting it each time

Comment: How I can realize that? So that I get every value in the div?

Comment: Use something like `+=` to append text instead of just `=` which resets the text.

Answer (score 2):

"Unfortunately, only the last value is displayed."

Because each iteration you are setting the `innerHTML` to i so at the last iteration it will be i and so the last value is 10.

"But why does console.log (i) show me every value of i in the console?"

You have 10 iterations meaning it will run 10 times because of the `for` loop.

So it will `console.log();` 10 times.